# How do I show and hide certain divs on page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to show and hide certain `div`s within my document.
I have put together code using `getElementById` and want to apply style.display to each element of array. I am not sure if this is possible.

Currently my code looks like this:

**Javascript**

```
<script>
function chart1() {
    var show = new array ["#chartdiv1", "#unit-price"];
    document.getElementByid("graph-container").show.style.display = "inline";
    var hide = new array ["#chartdiv2", "#unit-price-value",
        "#chartdiv3", "#unit-price-value"];
    document.getElementByid("graph-container").hide.style.display = "none";
};
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="graph-container">
    <!-- Unit Price Dollar -->
    <div id="unit-price" style="text-align: center; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #666; clear: both; margin-bottom: 20px;">VPM Global Select Opportunities Fund - Dollar Unit Price
        <br>Weekly: 2012/02/03 to 2014/10/24</div>
    <div id="chartdiv1" style="width:100%; height:600px;"></div>
    <!-- Unit Price Dollar Target Return -->
    <div id="unit-price-value" style="text-align: center; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #666; clear: both; margin-bottom: 20px;">Value of $1000 Invested at inception relative to Target Return
        <br>Weekly: 2012/02/03 to 2014/10/24</div>
    <div id="chartdiv2" style="width:100%; height:600px;"></div>
    <!-- Unit Price Rand Versus Inflation -->
    <div id="unit-price-rand" style="text-align: center; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #666; clear: both; margin-bottom: 20px;">Value of R1000 Invested at inception relative to Inflation Benchmarks
        <br>Weekly: 2012/02/03 to 2014/10/24</div>
    <div id="chartdiv3" style="width:100%; height:600px;"></div>
    <div style="text-align: center; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #666; clear: both; margin-top: 20px;">
        <br>* VPM GSO - VPM Global Select Opportunities Fund</div>
    <br>
</div>
<!-- End Graph Container-->
```

**Original Javascript that works in IE11, Safari, Opera, FireFox and Chrome**

This is the orignal code I created it worked in all the browsers except IE8-10, maybe someone can guide me on this.

```
function chart1() {
    document.getElementById("chartdiv1").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("unit-price").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("chartdiv2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("unit-price-value").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("chartdiv3").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("unit-price-rand").style.display = "none";
    };
    </script>
```

You help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If jQuery is an option then add jQuery tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are trying to do is this:

```
function chart1() {
    var show = ["chartdiv1", "unit-price"];
    for ( var i = 0; i < show.length; ++i ) 
         document.getElementById(show[i]).style.display = "inline";
    var hide = ["chartdiv2", "unit-price-value","chartdiv3", "unit-price-value"];
    for ( var i = 0; i < hide.length; ++i ) 
         document.getElementById(hide[i]).style.display = "none";
    };
```

In this way you itearate over the two arrays so that the elements in show are shown and the others are hidden.
The problems were:

- the IDs if you use plain js and not css or jQuery are without the #
- The correct syntax for array is Array
- You have to iterate over the elements in order to hide/show each of them
- You have to remove the hide/show after the getElementById selection, because in that way you are accessing to a property inside that Object

Comment: I have tried this code it does not seem to work, its good code and makes logical sense that if the  show array is greater than i its should display or not display. I even tried it with new Array and removed the #'s would there be anyhting else i can try on this code.

Comment: I tried on this jsFiddle and it seems to work:
http://jsfiddle.net/0w4bc0vo/

You can see just the two divs

Comment: I added my original code to the question would you be able to tell me whay it does not work in IE 8-10.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing pure JS and JQuery.

`hide()` and `show()` in JQUery

So, for you: `$("#graph-container").hide();`

`style.display = "none";` in pure JS

So, for you: `document.getElementByid("graph-container").style.display = "none";`

For the difference between `hidden` and `none`: [What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Comment: would you be able to guide with some come jQUERY code that would do the same function i am looking  for.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, it should work.

```
document.getElementById("graph-container").style.visibility="visible"; //Show the container
 var hide = new array ["#chartdiv2", "#unit-price-value","#chartdiv3", "#unit-price-value"];
    document.getElementById("graph-container").style.visibility="hidden"; //Hide the container
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using javascript

```
  document.getElementById("<your tag id>").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

And again to show the element, you can use,

```
  document.getElementById("<your tag id>").style.visibility = "visible";
```

A small demontration i submitted in Snippet. Check if it helps you.

```html
<html>
<body>

<div id="myP">This is a p element.</div>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Hide content of div</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction1()">Show content of div</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myP").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
  function myFunction1() {
    document.getElementById("myP").style.visibility = "visible";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Using Jquery, you can use `show()` and `hide()` method.
[JQuery show and hide method](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp)